# Import web-component (exported as es6 module) in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, es6-modules

I have a library which exports a set of web-components. The bundle is created using rollup and all exports are in place, eg.:
`export { Input, Button };` where `Input` and `Button` are es6 classes defined earlier in the bundle.
I have published it as npm package to a private npm repo and am now trying to import is to another angular application
`import { Input, Button } from '../../node_modules/@company/web-components';`

I also have tried to import them as `import '../../node_modules/@company/web-components';`

But webpack seems to treeshake that import as it doesn't see where it is used. The interesting thing, however, is that when the library is exported as `iife` the webpack doesn't treeshake it.

Is there a way to tell angular's webpack to include the specific import regardless whether it is referenced in the code or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a way to include es6 module from `node_modules` by adding the following line to `angular.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "projects": {
    "project-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "release.js",
                "input": "./node_modules/@company/web-components/dist/",
                "output": "."
              }
            ],
```

And then we can include it in `index.html` with typical module import:

```
<script type="module" src="release.js"></script>
```